# French Minhagim

Tags: minhag, ashkenazi, yekke

When I was in France over the summer, I noticed that, in general, the Ashkenazim followed German minhagim. Resultantly, it made me wonder whether there are any major differences between Minhag Rheinus and Minhag Tzarfat. If so, what are they?

If it makes a different, the schul where I davened had been founded by a rav trained at the Hildesheimer Yeshiva.

Comment: The folks with whom I ate also had French family names.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_France#17th_century says that there weren't too many Jews in France between the time of the Rishonim and until after the French Revolution. As such, I would assume that the France would have the same "customs" as America - Keep whatever customs you had from where ever you came from.

Comment: I don't know much about French communities, but I know they have a minhag of making really good cholent. Case in point when a French Chabadnik dropped by my shul and spent 4 hours before Shabbos perfecting a cholent fit for a king.

Comment: My grandmother's family were French Jews. Unfortunately, I have no clue about any minhagim.

Comment: @ezra, I should probably adjust this question, since most French Ashkenazim are of German extraction and their minhogim reflect this.

Comment: Isn't it because the Jews were expelled in 1394? The original French minhag was preserved in Asti, Fossano and Moncalvo (Apam) in Italy. I suppose those Jews in France, who are not coming from Poland, Russia or Northern Africa follow some Alsatian variant of the German rite.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Very interesting about the French family names. The sefardim in France don't have those, I think. Did they convert?

Comment: Well, there is a minhag in America (or wherever Chabad is) to sing the last "harachaman" in bentshing, as well as several niggunim, to the tune of the Marseillaise

Comment: @SAH, that's Chabad. I doubt that French kehillot do this

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the Goldschmidt Machzorim (for Rosh Hashanah, [here](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Goldschmidt_Machzor_Rosh_Hashonah.pdf), for Yom Kippur, [here](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Goldschmidt_Machzor_Yom_Kippur.pdf), and for Sukkos/Shemini Atzeres/Simchas Torah, [here](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Goldschmidt_Machzor_Succos.pdf)) you will see plenty of differences regarding the piyutim between Minhog Tzorfas and other Minhogim.

**Note:** There is also a Goldschmidt Machzor for Pesach and another one for Shavu'os, where you will find more differences between Mingog Tzorfas and other Mingogim, but they are not online.